# Populating RibbonComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, ribbon

I am learning WPF and have spent *waaaay* too much time trying to solve this simple task.

My goal is to add two `RibbonComboBox`es to a ribbon control. One for *Categories*, and another for *Subcategories*. Whenever the user changes the *Category*, I would like to have the *Subcategories* combo box update to show the subcategories for the current category.

**XAML:**

```
<RibbonTab Header="Home">
    <RibbonGroup Header="Category">
        <RibbonComboBox Label="Category:" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" SelectionBoxWidth="250" Focusable="False">
            <RibbonGallery Name="galCategory" DisplayMemberPath="Text" SelectedValuePath="Value">
            </RibbonGallery>
        </RibbonComboBox>
        <RibbonComboBox Label="Subcategory:" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" SelectionBoxWidth="250">
            <RibbonGallery Name="galSubcategory" DisplayMemberPath="Text" SelectedValuePath="Value">
            </RibbonGallery>
        </RibbonComboBox>
    </RibbonGroup>
</RibbonTab>
```

I found that only by adding the `RibbonGallery` element, I can access methods that allow me to populate the combo box. However, while my data shows in the list, the items cannot be selected by the user. (Clicking items in the list has no effect whatsoever.)

Can anyone tell me how to populate these controls?

*Note: Bonus points to anyone who can tell me how to make the two combo boxes align up to each other regardless of the length of text in the label!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `RibbonGalleryCategory` control inside `RibbonGallery` and then populate it. Add a selection change event listener to `RibbonGallery`:

**XAML:**

```
<RibbonComboBox Label="Category:" Name="rcmbCategory" SelectionBoxWidth="100" Height="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
    <RibbonGallery Name="galCategory" DisplayMemberPath="Text" SelectedValuePath="Value" SelectionChanged="RibbonGallery_SelectionChanged">
        <RibbonGalleryCategory Name="rgcCategory"/>
    </RibbonGallery>
</RibbonComboBox>
```

**.CS:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
        rgcCategory.Items.Add(i);
}

private void RibbonGallery_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(rcmbCategory.SelectionBoxItem.ToString());
}
```

Refer to [CodeProject: RibbonComboBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255322/Ribbon-WPF-ribbon-RibbonComboBox) for more information.